# How to pass value from the textbox to the sql query's parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, parameter-passing

I need some help here.

```
SET @LotId = '{0}%'

SELECT 
    coalesce(a.LOT_ID, b.LOT_ID,c.LOT_ID,d.LOT_ID) as LotId, 
    coalesce(a.CheckIn, b.CheckIn,c.CheckIn,d.CheckIn) as CheckIn,
    coalesce(a.CheckOut, b.CheckOut,c.CheckOut,d.CheckOut) as CheckOut,
    coalesce(a.StatusDesc, b.StatusDesc,c.StatusDesc,d.StatusDesc) as 
    StatusDesc 
FROM        
    LOT_LOC_BOND a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    LOT_LOC_IEBT b ON a.LOT_ID = b.LOT_ID  
                   AND a.CheckIn = b.CheckIn 
                   AND a.CheckOut = b.CheckOut 
                   AND a.StatusDesc = b.StatusDesc 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    LOT_LOC_MBT c ON b.LOT_ID = c.LOT_D  
                  AND b.CheckIn = c.CheckIn
                  AND b.CheckOut = c.CheckOut
                  AND b.StatusDesc = c.StatusDesc 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    LOT_LOC_SEAL d ON c.LOT_ID = d.LOT_ID
                   AND c.CheckIn = d.CheckIn
                   AND c.CheckOut = d.CheckOut
                   AND c.StatusDesc = d.StatusDesc
WHERE 
    a.LOT_ID = @LotId
```

I need to pass a value which known as Lotid from the textbox to the SQL query parameter, and I don't think the above query is a right way to do that.someone told me that using coalesce is forbidden if you want to pass the parameter.

I really need your help right now. I am using SQL Server 2014 for the query and Asp.net, vb.net in Visual Studio 2010 for the IDE, this system also are using two different pages. The textbox is on the first page and the result will be display at the second page.

Comment: You do this with whatever application code you are using for the textbox.  Examples include .net, php and coldfusion.

Comment: There's a fair bit of confusion here and lots of approaches.  You can use Entity Framework for example, or just create a string and execute against a database connection.  The COALESCE statement is a complete non sequitur as is the comments about first & second pages.  All I can say at this point is that a) you need to get clear in your mind what you are trying to do b) form a better question, c) Do not even consider adding the string from your text box to a SQL query string.

Comment: You have posted the sql code and mentioned the vb.net ASP.Net code.  truthfully to answer your question the vb.net code is more important.  There are many different ways to connect to SQL-Server from vb.net and the answer will vary based on what you have chosen.  But I do have to say this is a pretty common question and is documented pretty well across the internet try searching for how to pass a parameter from vb.net